# ¿Cómo puedo evitar este salto de linea?

Tags: c, windows, scanf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
int main()
{
int i,opcion;
printf("De los siguientes numeros entre cuales desea realizar la suma");
printf("\nPulse1=3\nPulse2=4\nPulse3=5\nPulse4=6");
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
      scanf("%i",&opcion);
  }
Sleep(500000);
}
```

Esa es la salida al guardar los datos en el scanf(lo de la foto)
  A mi me gustaria suprimir ese salto de linea para que apareciera uno al lado 
 de otro

Comment: Que tal Sergio, te falta una coma scanf("%i", &opcion);

Comment: cierto es que intente hacer un ejemplo rápido y me lo comí.Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que utilizas la funcion scanf que guarda el dato que le pediste hasta un espacio en blanco, entonces como le das enter para ingresar los datos te hara el salto de linea en la consola, si utilizas espacio(barra espaciador) y sigues ingresando los datos se guardaran correctamente puedes probar, pero si deseas que los datos se ingresen pegados, por ejemplo 1234 deberas usar otra funcion, como getchar(); y convertir a entero u otra, te dejo el output, lo unico que agregue a lo que enviaste es un printf en cada ciclo.
[image: output]